# How to extend windows server 2008 system volume?

Tags: windows-server-2008, partition

My system partition is running out of space and need to extend it.

Here is the scenario:

All volumes are on one disk and there is no raid. I have C:\ system partition thats full, I have a E:\ partition that has 50 GB of free space and Exchange is installed on it and I have a G:\ parition thats also 50Gb and its empty. I cant extend with G:\ partition because its not next to C :\ so Disk Management doesnt allow me to do that.

I thought about copying exchange files from E:\ to G:\ and then changing letters E to G and G to E. Is that going to mess up the exchange? Will exchange stop working even tho the files are still under E:....?

Then I would be able to format the volume next to c:\ and extend my system volume.

Possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You do not state which version of Exchange you are running and how Exchange is "installed" on E:, but if you have the Mailbox databases or the transport / transaction logs on E: you should do fine by just stopping all Exchange services, moving the data to another volumes, re-assigning drive letters and re-starting the services. You might have to take a look on your backup configuration though - Windows Server Backup for instance is not referring to disk drive letters but to volume GUIDs, making it back up the wrong (empty) disk.

Note that you would not need to "reformat" the formerly-known-as-E volume prior to extending your system volume, you will want to *delete* it instead. Volume extension can only be performed into vacant adjacent space not yet claimed by a partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use software like Acronis Disk Director or Easeus Partition Master Server to move and resize partitions however you like. Only thing is, some operations may require the server to be offline for the duration of the operation.

Programs like those are not limited to grow and shrink like the windows's disk management tool, they can also move partitions.